# confirm before submit using toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle, confirm

I have a enable/disable button for user ability. I want to add a confirmation before it gets turned on/off.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch1" checked data-switch="bool"/>
<label for="switch1" data-on-label="On" data-off-label="Off"></label>
```

js:

```
function(){
// I want to write a confirmation code here....
api_call(url, data, method)
}

// if not confirmed...
// return false..and dont toggle the button...
```

However, in my case (intially button on) its not sending the request if not confirmed but it will toggle the button (button Off). After I refresh, it sets to previous value.. (button on)

Please help me not to toggle the switch when request is not sent when not confirming and likewise

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the confirm dialogue present in JS
the confirm(...) will return true or false based on user selecting Yes or No

```
const isConfirmed = confirm('Toggle button?')  
if(isConfirmed) {
  // ... run your function
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use promise to solve your problem.

Using promises ensures that the UI state is not updated until the confirmation is resolved and the API call is completed successfully.

```
let confirmed = false;

const confirmAction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const isConfirmed = window.confirm('Do you confirm it?');
    confirmed = isConfirmed;
    
    if(confirmed) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject(new Error('Confirmation rejected.'));
    }
  });
 };
 
 const makeApiCall = (url, data, method) => {
    //API call implementation here
    //...
    //Return a promise that is based on the API response
 }
 
 const toggleButtonState = () => {
  confirmAction()
    .then(() => makeApiCall(yourUrl, yourData, yourMethod))
    .then(() => toggleButton())
    .cateh((error) => console.error(error));
 };
 
 const toggleButton = () => {
  if(confirmed) {
    //Toggle the button here
    //...
  }
 }
```

Comment: Complete waste of time and code to use promises here and you spelled catch wrong